# django inspectdb, how to write multiple table name during inspection

Tags: django, python-3.x

When I first execute this command it create model in my model.py but when I call it second time for  another table in same model.py file then that second table replace model of first can anyone told the reason behind that because I am not able to find perfect solution for that?

`$ python manage.py inspectdb tablename > v1/projectname/models.py`

When executing this command second time for  another table then it replace first table name.

`$ python manage.py inspectdb tablename2 > v1/projectname/models.py`

Answer (score 0):

`django-admin inspectdb [table [table ...]]`

[link to source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb)

Comment: hi  I got answer but different from this when I run this like [table[tablename, tablename]] then it shows 1146 error but I find out the way.
the command is
python manage.py inspectdb tablename1 tablename2 > v1/models.py

Comment: @DivanshuTak the brackets represent an optional argument. As you discovered, you shouldn't actually include them. This is a convention used in a lot of console help text.

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py inspectdb table1 table2 table3... > app_name/models.py`

Apply this command for inspection of multiple tables of one database in django.